# How to instantiate a template method of a template class with swig?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have a class in C++ which is a template class, and one method on this class is templated on another placeholder

```
template <class T>
class Whatever {
public:
    template <class V>
    void foo(std::vector<V> values);
}
```

When I transport this class to the swig file, I did

```
%template(Whatever_MyT) Whatever<MyT>;
```

Unfortunately, when I try to invoke `foo` on an instance of Whatever_MyT from python, I get an attribute error. I thought I had to instantiate the member function with

```
%template(foo_double) Whatever<MyT>::foo<double>;
```

which is what I would write in C++, but it does not work (I get a syntax error)

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 12):

Declare instances of the member templates first, then declare instances of the class templates.

#### Example

```
%module x

%inline %{
#include<iostream>
template<class T> class Whatever
{
    T m;
public:
    Whatever(T a) : m(a) {}
    template<class V> void foo(V a) { std::cout << m << " " << a << std::endl; }
};
%}

// member templates
// NOTE: You *can* use the same name for member templates,
//       which is useful if you have a lot of types to support.
%template(fooi) Whatever::foo<int>;
%template(food) Whatever::foo<double>;
// class templates.  Each will contain fooi and food members.
// NOTE: You *can't* use the same template name for the classes.
%template(Whateveri) Whatever<int>;
%template(Whateverd) Whatever<double>;
```

#### Output

```
>>> import x
>>> wi=x.Whateveri(5)
>>> wd=x.Whateverd(2.5)
>>> wi.fooi(7)
5 7
>>> wd.fooi(7)
2.5 7
>>> wi.food(2.5)
5 2.5
>>> wd.food(2.5)
2.5 2.5
```

**Reference:** [6.18 Templates](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn30) (search for "member template") in the [SWIG 2.0 Documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html).

Comment: It works really great, but how do you instantiate member function of multiple instances, say Whatever<float>::foo<float> and Whatever<double>::foo<float>. For me it always ends up with the latter.

Comment: @JensMunk, did you make sure to give each `%template` a different unique name?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the error. I use an older version of SWIG, so I will not comment on this further