# Swigging a class member function that is a template function

Tags: python, c++, swig

This question builds on the question: [How to instantiate a template method of a template class with swig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218929/how-to-instantiate-a-template-method-of-a-template-class-with-swig) .

However, compared to that question, the code I'm trying to wrap is a little different:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    template <class T>
     void f1(const string& firstArg, const T& value);
};
```

The *MyClass* is a regular C++ class, with one template function f1.

Attempt to wrap MyClass::f1:, i.e. the Swig .i file

```
 %template(f1String)    MyClass::f1<std::string>;
```

With the above, a Python client can do

```
o = MyClass
str1 = "A String"
o.f1String("", str1)
```

This interface require the Python client to learn about all different f1 function names, each one different depending on the type. Not so clean.

A cleaner interface can be obtained by overloading, extending in the interface file, e.g.

```
%extend MyClass {
   void f1(const string& s, const string& s1){
          $self->f1(s, s1);
   }
   void f1(const string& s, const int& anInt){
          $self->f1(s, anInt);
   }
}
```

This allow client code like this:

```
o = MyClass
str1 = "A String"
anInt = 34
o.f1("", str1)
o.f1("", anInt)
```

Question is, is there any way to obtain the interface above (by extending), *without extending*, using Swig?

Comment: Can you show the actual output instead of just "I get Type error"?

Comment: Also, if you suspect the nontemplate argument is the problem, why don't you test it? Temporarily add a `template <class T> void f2(const T& value);` and `%template(f2String) MyClass::f2<std::string>;` and see if that works. If not, you can rule that out, instead of just guessing.

Comment: Hold on, what happened to the error you were asking about? This seems like a completely different question than it was a minute ago.

Comment: My initial question had a problem in the T argument, not being a reference. I removed that, and so the code compiled fine. The question is about how to obtain a cleaner interface. Sorry for the confusion, abarnert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily the Python wrapper supports overloading, so you can simply instantiate the two methods with the same name and SWIG will do its magic to resolve the overloads at runtime.   See [6.18 Templates](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn30) in the chapter “SWIG and C++” of the documentation for more details.

**`test.i`**

```
%module example
%{
#include<iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    template <class T>
    void f1(const std::string& firstArg, const T& value) {
        std::cout << firstArg << ',' << value << '\n';
    }
};
%}

%include <std_string.i>

class MyClass {
public:
    template <class T>
    void f1(const std::string& firstArg, const T& value);
};

%extend MyClass {
    %template(f1) f1<std::string>;
    %template(f1) f1<int>;
}
```

**`test.py`**

```python
from example import *

o = MyClass()
str1 = "A String"
anInt = 34
o.f1("X", str1)
o.f1("Y", anInt)
```

Example workflow to compile and run:

```
$ swig -python -c++ test.i
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o _example.so -lpython2.7
$ python2.7 test.py
X,A String
Y,34
```

Comment: That is elegant indeed!